# Remove an element from an array by field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the next array:

```
0: {id: "10", tipo: "work"}
1: {id: "11", tipo: "work"}
2: {id: "24", tipo: "school"}
3: {id: "9", tipo: "work"}
4: {id: "25", tipo: "school"}
```

What I want to do is to remove an element from the array where two values match, for example, if `id = 24` and `tipo = school`, the array at the position 2, must be removed, I have this function to find the array key by the values:

```
function eliminarElementoArray(array,val1,val2){   
     for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       if (array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo == val2)                    
          return i;
       else
          return false;
     }
 }
```

The function does not work correctly, in some cases it returns false, others, it returns an incorrect value.

Finally here is where the array values are removed,  but it does not work because the previous function does not return the correct values:

```
selected.splice( eliminarElementoArray(selected, id, tipo), 1);
```

If someone can help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: post your array of object as `text` not as an `image`

Comment: Well, just from looking at your method, it will sometimes return false.  And you are giving the response of that to the splice method.  That's not valid.  You would want to get the response, check if it is not false, before giving that response to splice.

Comment: Also as your logic is currently written, if the first element does not match, you will return false, without considering any other elements in the array.....

Comment: yes, that's the problem, sometimes it returns false, but I do not know why, if all the fields match

Comment: as I said, if it doesn't match the first element in the array, it *returns false* for the first iteration.  it doesn't get a chance to do more iterations.  it is returning out of the function and ending the loop

Comment: What is the output you want @U.C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :**

**The *`return false;` statement inside `for` loop:*** The function will always check the first element of the array then if it does not match it will move to the `else` clause and return `false` without looping through the rest of the elements.

**Solution :**

You should move the return statement out of the loop so if no element of the array matches the passed arguments the function will return `false`.

**NOTE:** As @Taplar's comment says, It will be better to return a Truthy (no [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) value like `-1` for example since the `splice()` method will consider `false` as zero `0` and remove the first item.

```js
function eliminarElementoArray(array, val1, val2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo == val2)
      return i;
  }

  return -1;
}

var my_array = [{id: "10",tipo: "work"}, {id: "11",tipo: "work"}, {id: "24",tipo: "school"}, {id: "9",tipo: "work"}, {id: "25",tipo: "school"}];

console.log(eliminarElementoArray(my_array, "10", "work"));
console.log(eliminarElementoArray(my_array, "11", "fail test"));
console.log(eliminarElementoArray(my_array, "25", "school"));
```

Comment: Also be aware that if your conditional can match the first element; 0 is falsy.  So your conditional will need to check explicitly that the returned value is `!==` false

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @Taplar, you're right the `splice()` method will consider `false` as a zero and remove the first element.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Your code becomes:

```js
const array = [{id: 23, tipo: 'foo'}, {id: 25, tipo: 'school'}, {id: 24, tipo: 'school'}]

const filteredArray = array.filter(element => element.id !== 24 || element.tipo !== 'school')

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `return false` inside `else`, the function will return immediately after the first element.

```
function eliminarElementoArray(array,val1,val2){   
     for (i in array){
       if (array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo == val2)                    
          return i;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to your advantage.

```
const deleteElement = (idValue, tipoValue) => {
  return yourArrayName.filter(el => el.id !== idValue && el.tipe !== tipoValue)
}
```

Then pass the values to the `deleteElement` function, like so :

```
newArray = deleteElement('24','work')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [
 {id: "10", tipo: "work"},
 {id: "11", tipo: "work"},
 {id: "24", tipo: "school"},
 {id: "9", tipo: "work"},
 {id: "25", tipo: "school"}
]

function removeByIdAndTipo(idValue, tipoValue){
  return data.filter(({ id, tipo })=> { 
   return !(id === idValue && tipo === tipoValue)
  })
}

console.log("filteredData", removeByIdAndTipo("24", "school"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut method is

```
var data=[
   {id: "10", tipo: "work"},
   {id: "11", tipo: "work"},
   {id: "24", tipo: "school"},
   {id: "9", tipo: "work"},
   {id: "25", tipo: "school"}
]

var values=$.grep(data,p=>{
    return !(p.id === "24" && p.tipo === "school")
})

console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already pointed out, there are some logic error (like the function will return directly after first mismatch).

But for your use case, you don't need to loop first to find out that index which match both value, finally use `Array.splice` remove it.

**One solution** is Just loop the array, then push mismatch elements to one new array, finally return that new array.

```js
let test = [{
    id: "10",
    tipo: "work"
  },
  {
    id: "11",
    tipo: "work"
  },
  {
    id: "24",
    tipo: "school"
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    tipo: "work"
  },
  {
    id: "25",
    tipo: "school"
  }
]

function eliminarElementoArray(array, val1, val2) {
  let unmatch = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo == val2))
      unmatch.push(array[i])
  }
  return unmatch
}
console.log(eliminarElementoArray(test, 24, 'school'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lodash way.

```
   let arr = [
            { id: "10", tipo: "work" },
            { id: "11", tipo: "work" },
            { id: "24", tipo: "school" },
            { id: "9", tipo: "work" },
            { id: "25", tipo: "school" }
        ];
    function test(array, val1, val2){
            _.remove(array, item =>{
                return item.id == val1 && item.tipo == val2;
            })
        }
    test(arr, '9', 'work');
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    {
        id : "1",
        typo: "aba"
    },
    {
        id : "2",
        typo: "school"
    },
    {
        id : "3",
        typo: "alibaba"
    }
];

function removeItemByTypo(arr,id,typo){
    arr.forEach(function(elem,index) {
      if(elem.id == id && elem.typo == typo){
        arr.splice(index,1);
      }
    });
}

removeItemByTypo(arr,"2","school");
console.log(arr);
```

You can use forEach in array use 2 args is elem and index, elem to find object by id and typo and index to splice it. Hope my answer is clear!

Answer (score 0):

```
   var array = [];
   array[1] = {id: "10", tipo: "work"};
   array[2] = {id: "11", tipo: "work"};
   array[3] = {id: "24", tipo: "school"};
   array[4] = {id: "9", tipo: "work"};
   array[5] = {id: "25", tipo: "school"};

   function eliminarElementoArray(array,val1,val2){
       for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
           if(array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo == val2) {
              array.splice(i, 1);
              break;
           }
       }
   }
   array.splice(eliminarElementoArray(array,11,"work"), 1);
   console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should compare the string (tipo) with `===` and not with `==`.
2. You must delete the else because with this else you're only comparing the first element; your function should be like this:

   ```
   function eliminarElementoArray(array,val1,val2){   
     for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       if (array[i].id == val1 && array[i].tipo === val2)                  
           return i;
     }
   }
   ```

I hope this help you :)